# Как вести информацию в статусбар?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У меня есть главное окно, нам нём кнопка, которая открывает новое модальное окно (кнопка Параметры).[image: Главное окно]У этого модального окна есть кнопка, которая его закрывает (кнопка Сохранить). [image: Модальное окно] Хочется, чтобы при закрытии модального окна по нажатию этой кнопки в статусбаре отображалась надпись.

Мне не понятно назначение указателя ui при создании окна. Как ссылаться на этот указатель, но у главного окна?

```
ParametersWindow::ParametersWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ParametersWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

UPD:
У MainWindow создал публичный метод:

```
void MainWindow::messageInStatusBarMainWindow(const QString &message) {
ui->statusBar->showMessage(message);
```

}

При нажатии на кнопку Сохранить в окне с параметрами он вызывается:

```
    void ParametersWindow::on_save_button_clicked()
{
    dynamic_cast<MainWindow *>(ParametersWindow::parent())->messageInStatusBarMainWindow("Настройки сохранены");
    ParametersWindow::close();
}
```

Однако приложение валится при нажатии на Сохранить.

Comment: Например, после закрытия модального окна из кода главного окна, вызовите у главного окна `ui->statusBar->showMessage("hello world!")`

Comment: Да, но метод закрытия модального окна принадлежит классу этого окна. Где у главного окна вы предлагаете вызывать?

Comment: Если окно модальное, то вызываете его через `exec()`, а значит пока тот диалог открыт, код дальше `exec()` не пойдет, вот после `exec()` и добавьте. Это самый простой и хороший вариант. Сложнее -- у диалога завести сигнал и по событию диалога посылать сигнал, который будет связан с слотом главного окна или самого `ui->statusBar`

Comment: @gil9red, это был бы отличный вариант, будь у модального окна одна кнопка его закрывающая. Тот вариант, который вы предложили будет всегда выводить сообщение о сохранении данных

Comment: Это еще отличный вариант -- добавьте, например, в ваш диалог булевую переменную и при закрытии через ту кнопку сохранения ставьте ей true, а после exec() проверяйте что у него та переменная `true` и вызывайте код с статусбаром. Ну, или второй вариант: на сигнал клика той кнопки сохранения вызывайте нужный вам метод у главного окна

Comment: >> Хочется, чтобы при закрытии модального окна по нажатию этой кнопки в статусбаре отображалась надпись.<< В чём проблемы? Где ваш код?

Comment: >>Как ссылаться на этот указатель, но у главного окна?<< Передайте указатель другой форме... В чём сложности?

Comment: @test123, я пытался тыкаться в ui главного окна через parent: ((MainWindow *)parent())->ui->statusBar->setText("Настройки сохранены"); Но ничего хорошего не вышло, т.к. ui — приватная вещь.

Comment: @gil9red, второй вариант более изящный, чем первый. Спасибо

Comment: @ArseniySpiridonov, оформите, тогда ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа?  :) Весь код не нужно только набросок с решением проблемы

Comment: @gil9red, если бы оно ещё не валилось при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: С какой ошибкой падает?

Comment: @gil9red, неожиданное завершение

Comment: а в `on_save_button_clicked()` что возвращает `parent()`? null?

Comment: @gil9red, да. Т.к. не было указано, кто является parent у модального окна. Проблема решена!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Силами комментирующих было найдено практичное решение:
В классе главного окна был создан публичный метод, выводящий сообщение в statusBar:

```
void MainWindow::messageInStatusBarMainWindow(QString message) {
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(message, 2000);
```

}

В методе, обрабатывающем нажатие кнопки Сохранить у модального окна этот метод вызывается, где в параметры и передаётся нужное сообщение:

```
    void ParametersWindow::on_save_button_clicked()
{
    dynamic_cast<MainWindow *>(parent())->messageInStatusBarMainWindow(tr("Настройки сохранены"));
    ParametersWindow::close();
}
```

Comment: Кривоватое решение, прямо скажем

Answer (score 0):

Надо завести флаг в диалоге, показывающий, принят ли диалог, или отклонен, и геттер для этого флага.

В `showEvent` диалога устанавливаем флаг в `false`

При нажатии на кнопку "сохранить" устанавливаем флаг в `true`, теперь окружающие классы могут понять, что диалог принят

В главном окне после вызова `exec` диалога проверяем состояние флага через публичный геттер диалога и в зависимости от возвращенного значения записываем строку в статусбар.